# Join random row from second table

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have a left table with (6 million) ID variables, and a right table with (200) dates. I want to assign a random date to the IDs, so that each date occurs approximately as much as the others (uniform distribution). I use SQL in Teradata.

ID

```
A
B
C
D
```

date

```
1may2023
2may2023
```

result (but can be another random combination)

```
A - 1may2023
B - 2may2023
C - 2may2023
D - 1may2023
```

I tried cross joining the two tables, adding a column with random numbers, then picking the row with the lowest rank in this number per ID. This seems to work, but I have a feeling there is a better solution where I directly join a random date from the second table.

```
CREATE TABLE cross_join AS 
SELECT t1.id, t2.date, random(1,200) as rnd
from t1
cross join t2

SELECT id, date
from cross_join
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rnd) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a terradata instance to try but the following SQL should work:

```sql
with ranked_dates as
(
    select 
        date,
        row_number() over(partition by '' order by date asc) as rownum
    from ids
),
ranked_ids as
(
    select
        id,
        row_number() over(partition by '' order by id asc) as rownum
    from dates
),
range_ranked_ids as
(
    select
        id,
        mod(rownum, <insert number of dates here>) + 1 as rownum
    from ranked_ids
)
select
    i.id,
    d.date
from
    ranked_ids i
    inner join
    ranked_dates d
    on i.rownum = d.rownum;
```

Make sure you replace `<insert number of dates here>` with the number of dates in the dates table.